# Запуск QTcpServer на Astra Linux SE 1.5 в мандатном режиме, отличном от 0

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian, astra-linux

Собственно если запускаю listen() в нулевом сеансе, всё нормально.
Если отличном от нулевого, то сыпится:

```
QAbstractSocket::UnknownError "Unknown Error"
```

Привилегий **parsec** на юзера накинул, не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отключи ipv6. Вернее делай listen только для ipv4